# Twofish gpg:WARNING: message was not integrity protected

Tags: gnupg

I get this warning while I decrypt a Twofish-encrypted file in GPG.

> WARNING: message was not integrity protected.

From what I found online, this warning should only come up for CAST5, not for AES256 or Twofish. Why does this occur? And is there a way to prevent this warning?

I use GPG on Ubuntu 12.04 GNU/Linux.

Comment: I'd guess you only encrypted the message (with an unauthenticated mode like CFB or CBC) without applying a MAC or digital signature.

Comment: No, I encrypted the file with gpg this way.

> "gpg -s -armor --symmetric TWOFISH filename"

From the man page, I found that -s option signs it with my RSA key.

Answer (score 0):

How was the file encrypted? OpenPGP provides an option to integrity protect your ciphertext, called MDC.  Please note this is not the same as MAC or a signature.

Comment: Force-mdc option in GPG is required only for CAST5, not for 256bit key size like in AES256 or Twofish.

Comment: That's why it throws a warning, not an error I guess?

Comment: Yes, it's only a warning - which it should NOT throw for Twofish or AES256 in GPG, because their block sizes are above 64 bits.  (I should have said block-size in previous comment instead of key size, sorry!)
The default algorithm "CAST5"  requires force-mdc due to its lower block size. 

I found this info here : http://is.gd/JggekU